# localhost/test.php is also reachable under localhost/test/

Tags: php, apache, webserver

What is wrong with my apache-conf, why is the file also reachable under a folder-path without an extension? I haven't set any rewrite rules and there are no .htaccess files. 
This is the default os x apache installation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apache's [content negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html) has an option called [`MultiViews`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) which makes a file available without its extension:

> The effect of MultiViews is as follows: if the server receives a request for /some/dir/foo, if /some/dir has MultiViews enabled, and /some/dir/foo does not exist, then the server reads the directory looking for files named foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then chooses the best match to the client's requirements.